# Facebook App Notifications - can only deliver to some users

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created a script in php that successfully posts notifications to my app, but the weird thing is that it only works for some accounts?

I tried creating it with curl, but that didn't work (Facebook returned blank result if I posted correctly, but any errors gave a JSON string with error description - baffling). Anyway I have a javascript that just gets ECHO'ed for each user and then I visit the .php page in a browser to deliver notifications. That works, but only for some users.

JS looks like:

```
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">

        var postURL = \"https://graph.facebook.com/\" + $id + \"/notifications\";
        var postString = \"access_token=[myaccesstoken for my app]&href=&template=Your card registration has been processed. Click here to view your membership.\";

$.ajax({ 
            type        : \"POST\",
            url         : postURL, 
            data        : postString, 
            success     : function(data) {
            }
        });


        </script>
        Notified $id<br>
        ";
```

This works and prints a "Notified (id)" for each line. I don't see any pattern at all. It seems to just randomly fail and not fail. Failure means POST response is 400 bad request, and no notification is delivered. 200 OK and the user gets a notification.

Anyone care to elaborate on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - after a lot of intense trial and error, I came to the conclusion that it was the post itself that went wrong. I tried using a simple HTML post form, and that worked for everyone. Then I jumped back to cURL, but no matter what I did with that, it failed. I then stumbled across this function, and that worked perfectly for all users:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
$params = array('http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'content' => $data
));
if ($optional_headers!== null) {
$params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
}
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
}
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) {
throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
}
return $response;
}
```

Used like, where $id is a for loop of users:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $id . "/notifications";
$data = "access_token=myaccesstoken&template=Finally this works!";
echo do_post_request($url,$data);
```

and boom, JSON success returned. I have no idea why cURL didn't do the trick (and I tried a LOT).